# ICE Failed WebRTC in different Networks [Firefox]

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

I got this problem, i have a webapp running in a server, with domain and works, if I connect and videocall to another pc (remember my server it's online in linode server) in the same network (for example my home) I don't have any problems, but if I connect one laptop in my house and other in my work, (different networks) the connection didn't work, i try every STUN /TURN Signaling and I keep with  numb.viagenie.ca with BOTH STUN AND TURN servers.
When I see about:webrtc appears both connections my house and my laptop IP's and ports, but didn't work and appears ICE FAILED.
This is my RTCClient.js (My webRTC logic):

```
var PeerManager = (function (room, cbMessages) {
var remote = window.document.getElementById('remote');
var localId,
    config = {
        peerConnectionConfig: {
            iceServers: [
                /* { 'url': 'stun:stun01.sipphone.com' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.ekiga.net' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.fwdnet.net' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.ideasip.com' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.iptel.org' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.schlund.de' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stunserver.org' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.softjoys.com' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.voiparound.com' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.voipbuster.com' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.voipstunt.com' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.voxgratia.org' },
                 { 'url': 'stun:stun.xten.com' },
                 { 'url': "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com" },*/
                { 'url': "stun:numb.viagenie.ca" },
                {
                    'url': "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
                    'credential': 'xxxxxx',
                    'username': 'xxxxxxxx'
                },
                {
                    'url': "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
                    'credential': 'xxxxxxx',
                    'username': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                },

                /*{
                    'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
                    'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                    'username': '28224511:1379330808'
                },
                {
                    'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
                    'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                    'username': '28224511:1379330808'
                },*/
            ]
        },
        peerConnectionConstraints: {
            optional: [
                { "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true }
            ]
        }
    },
    peerDatabase = {},
    localStream,
    //remoteVideoContainer = document.getElementById('remoteVideosContainer'),
    socket = io('http://xxxxx');


//METODO CON EL QUE AUTOMATICAMENTE SE DISPARA CUANDO SE ESTABLECE LA CONEXION CON EL SERVIDOR
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Se ha establecido la conexion con el servidor');
    socket.emit('roomSetup', room);
});
socket.on('id', function (clientId) {
    cbMessages('id', clientId);
})
socket.on('message', handleMessage);
socket.on('numberQueue', function (action) {
    console.log("Recepcion en rtcClient del numberQueue");
    cbMessages('numberQueue', action);
})
socket.on('readytoCall', function (action) {
    console.log("Recepcion en rtcClient del readytoCall");
    cbMessages('readytoCall', action);
})
socket.on('startSession', function (action) {
    console.log('Recepcion en rtcClient del startSession');
    cbMessages('startSession', action);
})
socket.on('syncCounters', function (action) {
    console.log('Recepcion en rtcClient del syncCounters');
    cbMessages('syncCounters', action);
})
socket.on('id', function (id) {
    localId = id;
});

function addPeer(remoteId) {
    var peer = new Peer(config.peerConnectionConfig, config.peerConnectionConstraints);
    peer.pc.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        if (event.candidate) {
            send('candidate', remoteId, {
                label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: event.candidate.candidate
            });
        }
    };
    /* peer.pc.ontrack = function (event) {
         attachMediaStream(remote, event.streams[0]);
         console.log(remote, event.streams[0]);
     }*/
    peer.pc.onaddstream = function (event) {

        attachMediaStream(remote, event.stream); /*peer.remoteVideoEl*/
        // remoteVideosContainer.appendChild(peer.remoteVideoEl);
        console.log(remote, event.stream);
    };
    peer.pc.onremovestream = function (event) {
        peer.remoteVideoEl.src = '';
        remoteVideosContainer.removeChild(peer.remoteVideoEl);
    };
    peer.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function (event) {
        switch (
        (event.srcElement // Chrome
            || event.target) // Firefox
            .iceConnectionState) {
            case 'disconnected':
                remoteVideosContainer.removeChild(peer.remoteVideoEl);
                break;
        }
    };
    peerDatabase[remoteId] = peer;

    return peer;
}
function answer(remoteId) {
    var pc = peerDatabase[remoteId].pc;
    pc.createAnswer(
        function (sessionDescription) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
            send('answer', remoteId, sessionDescription);
        },
        error
    );
}
function offer(remoteId) {
    var pc = peerDatabase[remoteId].pc;
    pc.createOffer(
        function (sessionDescription) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
            send('offer', remoteId, sessionDescription);
        },
        error
    );
}
function handleMessage(message) {
    var type = message.type,
        from = message.from,
        pc = (peerDatabase[from] || addPeer(from)).pc;

    console.log('received ' + type + ' from ' + from);

    switch (type) {
        case 'init':
            toggleLocalStream(pc);
            offer(from);
            break;
        case 'offer':
            pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.payload), function () { }, error);
            answer(from);
            break;
        case 'answer':
            pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.payload), function () { }, error);
            break;
        case 'candidate':
            if (pc.remoteDescription) {
                pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate({
                    sdpMLineIndex: message.payload.label,
                    sdpMid: message.payload.id,
                    candidate: message.payload.candidate
                }), function () { }, error);
            }
            break;
    }
}
function send(type, to, payload) {
    console.log('sending ' + type + ' to ' + to);

    socket.emit('message', {
        to: to,
        type: type,
        payload: payload
    });
}
function toggleLocalStream(pc) {
    if (localStream) {
        (!!pc.getLocalStreams().length) ? pc.removeStream(localStream) : pc.addStream(localStream);
    }
}
function error(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

return {
    getId: function () {
        return localId;
    },

    setLocalStream: function (stream) {

        // if local cam has been stopped, remove it from all outgoing streams.
        if (!stream) {
            for (id in peerDatabase) {
                pc = peerDatabase[id].pc;
                if (!!pc.getLocalStreams().length) {
                    pc.removeStream(localStream);
                    offer(id);
                }
            }
        }

        localStream = stream;
    },

    toggleLocalStream: function (remoteId) {
        peer = peerDatabase[remoteId] || addPeer(remoteId);
        toggleLocalStream(peer.pc);
    },

    peerInit: function (remoteId) {
        peer = peerDatabase[remoteId] || addPeer(remoteId);
        console.log('send init');
        send('init', remoteId, null);

    },

    peerRenegociate: function (remoteId) {
        offer(remoteId);
    },

    send: function (type, payload) {
        socket.emit(type, payload);
    }
};

});
var Peer = function (pcConfig, pcConstraints) {
    this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcConstraints);
    this.remoteVideoEl = document.createElement('video');
    this.remoteVideoEl.controls = true;
    this.remoteVideoEl.autoplay = true;
}
```

And this is My Adapter.js

```
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2014 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree.
 */

/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2014 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree.
 */

'use strict';

var RTCPeerConnection = null;
var getUserMedia = null;
var attachMediaStream = null;
var reattachMediaStream = null;
var webrtcDetectedBrowser = null;
var webrtcDetectedVersion = null;

function maybeFixConfiguration(pcConfig) {
  if (!pcConfig) {
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < pcConfig.iceServers.length; i++) {
    if (pcConfig.iceServers[i].hasOwnProperty('urls')) {
      pcConfig.iceServers[i].url = pcConfig.iceServers[i].urls;
      delete pcConfig.iceServers[i].urls;
    }
  }
}

if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
  console.log('This appears to be Firefox');

  window.webrtcDetectedBrowser = 'firefox';

  window.webrtcDetectedVersion =
    parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/([0-9]+)\./)[1], 10);

  // The RTCPeerConnection object.
  RTCPeerConnection = function (pcConfig, pcConstraints) {
    // .urls is not supported in FF yet.
    maybeFixConfiguration(pcConfig);
    return new mozRTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcConstraints);
  };

  // The RTCSessionDescription object.
  RTCSessionDescription = mozRTCSessionDescription;

  // The RTCIceCandidate object.
  RTCIceCandidate = mozRTCIceCandidate;

  // Get UserMedia (only difference is the prefix).
  // Code from Adam Barth.
  window.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  navigator.getUserMedia = getUserMedia;

  // Creates iceServer from the url for FF.
  window.createIceServer = function (url, username, password) {
    var iceServer = null;
    var urlParts = url.split(':');
    if (urlParts[0].indexOf('stun') === 0) {
      // Create iceServer with stun url.
      iceServer = {
        'url': url
      };
    } else if (urlParts[0].indexOf('turn') === 0) {
      if (webrtcDetectedVersion < 27) {
        // Create iceServer with turn url.
        // Ignore the transport parameter from TURN url for FF version <=27.
        var turnUrlParts = url.split('?');
        // Return null for createIceServer if transport=tcp.
        if (turnUrlParts.length === 1 ||
          turnUrlParts[1].indexOf('transport=udp') === 0) {
          iceServer = {
            'url': turnUrlParts[0],
            'credential': password,
            'username': username
          };
        }
      } else {
        // FF 27 and above supports transport parameters in TURN url,
        // So passing in the full url to create iceServer.
        iceServer = {
          'url': url,
          'credential': password,
          'username': username
        };
      }
    }
    return iceServer;
  };

  window.createIceServers = function (urls, username, password) {
    var iceServers = [];
    // Use .url for FireFox.
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      var iceServer = createIceServer(urls[i],
        username,
        password);
      if (iceServer !== null) {
        iceServers.push(iceServer);
      }
    }
    return iceServers;
  };

  // Attach a media stream to an element.
  window.attachMediaStream = function (element, stream) {
    console.log('Attaching media stream');
    element.mozSrcObject = stream;
    element.play();
  };

  window.reattachMediaStream = function (to, from) {
    console.log('Reattaching media stream');
    to.mozSrcObject = from.mozSrcObject;
    to.play();
  };

} else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
  console.log('This appears to be Chrome');

  window.webrtcDetectedBrowser = 'chrome';
  // Temporary fix until crbug/374263 is fixed.
  // Setting Chrome version to 999, if version is unavailable.
  var result = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);
  if (result !== null) {
    window.webrtcDetectedVersion = parseInt(result[2], 10);
  } else {
    window.webrtcDetectedVersion = 999;
  }

  // Creates iceServer from the url for Chrome M33 and earlier.
  window.createIceServer = function (url, username, password) {
    var iceServer = null;
    var urlParts = url.split(':');
    if (urlParts[0].indexOf('stun') === 0) {
      // Create iceServer with stun url.
      iceServer = {
        'url': url
      };
    } else if (urlParts[0].indexOf('turn') === 0) {
      // Chrome M28 & above uses below TURN format.
      iceServer = {
        'url': url,
        'credential': password,
        'username': username
      };
    }
    return iceServer;
  };

  // Creates iceServers from the urls for Chrome M34 and above.
  window.createIceServers = function (urls, username, password) {
    var iceServers = [];
    if (webrtcDetectedVersion >= 34) {
      // .urls is supported since Chrome M34.
      iceServers = {
        'urls': urls,
        'credential': password,
        'username': username
      };
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var iceServer = createIceServer(urls[i],
          username,
          password);
        if (iceServer !== null) {
          iceServers.push(iceServer);
        }
      }
    }
    return iceServers;
  };

  // The RTCPeerConnection object.
  RTCPeerConnection = function (pcConfig, pcConstraints) {
    // .urls is supported since Chrome M34.
    if (webrtcDetectedVersion < 34) {
      maybeFixConfiguration(pcConfig);
    }
    return new webkitRTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcConstraints);
  };

  // Get UserMedia (only difference is the prefix).
  // Code from Adam Barth.
  window.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
  navigator.getUserMedia = getUserMedia;

  // Attach a media stream to an element.
  window.attachMediaStream = function (element, stream) {
    if (typeof element.srcObject !== 'undefined') {
      element.srcObject = stream;
    } else if (typeof element.mozSrcObject !== 'undefined') {
      element.mozSrcObject = stream;
    } else if (typeof element.src !== 'undefined') {
      element.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
      console.log('Error attaching stream to element.');
    }
  };

  window.reattachMediaStream = function (to, from) {
    to.src = from.src;
  };
} else {
  console.log('Browser does not appear to be WebRTC-capable');
}


// Returns the result of getUserMedia as a Promise.
function requestUserMedia(constraints) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var onSuccess = function (stream) {
      resolve(stream);
    };
    var onError = function (error) {
      reject(error);
    };

    try {
      getUserMedia(constraints, onSuccess, onError);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = {
    RTCPeerConnection: RTCPeerConnection,
    getUserMedia: getUserMedia,
    attachMediaStream: attachMediaStream,
    reattachMediaStream: reattachMediaStream,
    webrtcDetectedBrowser: webrtcDetectedBrowser,
    webrtcDetectedVersion: webrtcDetectedVersion
    //requestUserMedia: not exposed on purpose.
    //trace: not exposed on purpose.
  };
}
```

[STUN AND TURN ICE Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/205mg.png)

```
SDP

SDP local

v=0

o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-52.0.2 4443962319420549785 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=-

t=0 0

a=sendrecv

a=fingerprint:sha-256 A0:E0:C7:7E:3A:3B:4E:88:14:A9:D4:1F:A6:08:0B:C6:97:05:BC:33:4B:A5:CE:F8:CC:20:79:B1:BC:96:AF:17

a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0 sdparta_1

a=ice-options:trickle

a=msid-semantic:WMS *

m=audio 62832 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 101

c=IN IP4 190.117.88.12

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 ::38c8:a270:c7ff:d856 62830 typ host

a=candidate:6 1 UDP 2122187007 ::b43e:ec0d:7743:c6 62831 typ host

a=candidate:12 1 UDP 2122121471 192.168.0.38 62832 typ host

a=candidate:13 1 UDP 1685921791 190.117.88.12 62832 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.38 rport 62832

a=sendrecv

a=end-of-candidates

a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1

a=fmtp:101 0-15

a=ice-pwd:51e616b53508d2921fdde4894fe81529

a=ice-ufrag:9bfab4a4

a=mid:sdparta_0

a=msid:{2d638fea-7857-49cb-80a8-985d96460b21} {b82b166d-9a6e-4fc5-a10e-bb597ce567f6}

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=setup:active

a=ssrc:2090540075 cname:{794f53ca-9dd9-43f0-8d17-babc96ab5d2d}

m=video 62832 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120

c=IN IP4 190.117.88.12

a=sendrecv

a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60

a=ice-pwd:51e616b53508d2921fdde4894fe81529

a=ice-ufrag:9bfab4a4

a=mid:sdparta_1

a=msid:{2d638fea-7857-49cb-80a8-985d96460b21} {16b00fa2-9fbd-48ed-acd7-f14d80f4fa5d}

a=rtcp-fb:120 nack

a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli

a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir

a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000

a=setup:active

a=ssrc:2849290137 cname:{794f53ca-9dd9-43f0-8d17-babc96ab5d2d}

SDP remoto

v=0

o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-52.0.2 4028535757436800601 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=-

t=0 0

a=sendrecv

a=fingerprint:sha-256 E6:53:BD:DC:C0:74:F0:DE:2B:53:60:BF:41:45:F3:6D:61:64:82:FC:C4:61:0E:52:11:1F:A3:17:EF:58:4C:81

a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0 sdparta_1

a=ice-options:trickle

a=msid-semantic:WMS *

m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.101 62841 typ host

a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.1.101 62842 typ host

a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 181.66.165.192 5654 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 62841

a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 181.66.165.192 5655 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 62842

a=sendrecv

a=extmap:1/sendonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1

a=fmtp:101 0-15

a=ice-pwd:84d2a654605c91ba448fc90003f8c79e

a=ice-ufrag:0628a660

a=mid:sdparta_0

a=msid:{e08aacff-06fd-4f6d-ba42-408b4948501d} {209331a1-d401-4dea-8667-cf81750a5a63}

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=setup:actpass

a=ssrc:1248822540 cname:{f918048b-0188-438e-b0bb-a223d8d4ae07}

m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 121 126 97

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.101 62843 typ host

a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.1.101 62844 typ host

a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 181.66.165.192 5656 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 62843

a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 181.66.165.192 5657 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 62844

a=sendrecv

a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1

a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60

a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60

a=ice-pwd:84d2a654605c91ba448fc90003f8c79e

a=ice-ufrag:0628a660

a=mid:sdparta_1

a=msid:{e08aacff-06fd-4f6d-ba42-408b4948501d} {7a9fa748-c382-4134-a3d4-b7e48afa95fa}

a=rtcp-fb:120 nack

a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli

a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir

a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb

a=rtcp-fb:121 nack

a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli

a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir

a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb

a=rtcp-fb:126 nack

a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli

a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir

a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb

a=rtcp-fb:97 nack

a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli

a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir

a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000

a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000

a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=setup:actpass

a=ssrc:109206018 cname:{f918048b-0188-438e-b0bb-a223d8d4ae07}

Estadísticas RDP
inbound_rtp_audio_0

Local: 19:08:53 GMT-0500 inboundrtp SSRC: 0
inbound_rtp_video_1

Local: 19:08:53 GMT-0500 inboundrtp SSRC: 0
outbound_rtp_video_1

Local: 19:08:53 GMT-0500 outboundrtp SSRC: 2849290137
outbound_rtp_audio_0

Local: 19:08:53 GMT-0500 outboundrtp SSRC: 2090540075
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your browser is not gathering any candidates with "typ relay", only "typ host" and "typ srflx". This suggests that the credentials you're using are wrong. See the section ["Example 1 - My WebRTC app works locally but not on a different network!"](http://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/)

The list of servers looks like you're trying to use a "free" one and... no, there are no free servers.

Comment: Interesting article, i got superreflexive and host candidates but no relay, and yes, maybe there is the problem, can you advice me one TURN server on demand? or one good how to build my own TURN server?

Comment: http://numb.viagenie.ca/ actually provides a free service -- with your own account. In the end you'll probably end up setting up coturn yourself or go for the likes of [xirsys](https://xirsys.com/) or [bit6](https://bit6.com/webrtc-stun-turn/)

Comment: Hey I've had a similar issue except I set up my own coturn server on AWS but my web app on AWS still gets the same issue. I've tested out my coturn server and it works on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/